# windows install autoconf-2.69 You must run ./configure before running 'make'

Tags: windows, installation

Under the unzipped direcotry autoconf-2.69, I execute this command right after I execute the "**./configure**" command

```
$ make install
```

However, the terminal(cygwin) gave me this:

> - There seems to be no Makefile in this directory.
> - You must run ./configure before running 'make'.
> - C:\MinGW\bin\make.exe: *** [abort-due-to-no-makefile] Error 1

Why wasn't the Makefile produced? Thanks.

Comment: Probably because the run of `configure` failed. A successful run would have created a Makefile for you. But since you're not providing any info on your configure-run, this is more or less only a guess.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think you are right.  Actually I change my method of installing -- I use cygwin to install autoconf.